# Yocto - Use a variable in a patch

Tags: patch, yocto

Can one use a Yocto variable, like, say, `${MACHINE}`, in a patch file?

This is quite a general question, probably somebody can provide a quick example or just say "impossible".

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it suffices to use `${MACHINE}` within `SRC_URI` or append patch files using a machine-specific append-override.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, yes - if one needs to select a specific patch per machine type, it would be useful. But the question is actually more general, discussing a possibility of providing a Yocto variable content to a patch file.

Answer (score 2):

As @Khem wrote, in many cases you should rather avoid doing that in order to keep the code clean. If you really need to do it, you can use this (write a patch containing a placeholder string `#TO_BE_REPLACED#` ):

```
my_patch.patch:
"foobar"#TO_BE_REPLACED"foobar"
```

```py
SRC_URI += "my_patch.patch"

python do_unpack:append() {
    import subprocess
    bb.note("MY_YOCTO_VARIABLE: %s" % d.getVar('MY_YOCTO_VARIABLE'))
    cmd = d.expand("sed -i 's/#TO_BE_REPLACED#/%s/g' ${WORKDIR}/my_patch.patch" % d.getVar('MY_YOCTO_VARIABLE'))
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
}
```

You can also see an example of a yocto recipe modifying a source-file using yocto variables [here](https://github.com/kraj/meta-clang/blob/33cacf181b776a8dcda1c5e7e908bf66b0690e02/recipes-devtools/clang/llvm-project-source.inc#L61). It first applies the patch, adding a string to the file which then gets replaced by an extra function executing sed. This is a better approach to the one described above.

Comment: This is an interesting alternative. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there is no other way. You can't directly use a yocto variable in a patch file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not impossible but it will be wrong. Yocto variables are better kept to yocto build meta-data alone. Moreover this will not tie packages to yocto build environment.

Comment: If kept generic or extensible, then not. This is pretty common. E.g.  autoconfig's "--host=" parameter or Qt's qmake spec files in meta-qt5

Comment: its not clear what part of answer are you refuting here. Can you clarify more ?

Answer (score 1):

You achieve what you want by adding a post patch task to replace a variable, let's say `REPLACEME` with `${MACHINE}` using `sed` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you improve your answer by sharing an example (or a link to one) for me an others?