# How to add a variable in a Yocto patch

Tags: yocto, patch

I currently have a patch in Yocto for the U-Boot source code, but I want it to be dependent on file size (particularly the size of the kernel image). What's the best way to go about getting this variable into my patch?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, what is the problem with a Uboot and with kernel size?

Comment: @CleitonBueno the patch I made adds some redundancy to the kernel files (basically everything in /boot). On build, I want yocto to create constants in the u-boot code for these file sizes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yocto - Use a variable in a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789209/yocto-use-a-variable-in-a-patch)